# Find the metric so that this map is a contraction

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fixed-point-theorems, contraction-operator

Let $y_1, y_2 >0$ and $y_{n}=\frac{2}{y_{n-1}+y_{n-2}}$ for $n\ge 3$. I know that this sequence is converging and that $y_n \to 1$ as $n\to \infty$. Let us write $Y_n = (y_n,y_{n+1})$ and $f(a,b)=(b,\frac{2}{a+b})$ so that $f(Y_n)=Y_{n+1}$. My question is the following:

> Is it possible to find a metric on $\mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R}_+$ such that $f$ is a
> contraction mapping?

An idea would be to look at $\nabla f = \begin{bmatrix}0 & -\frac{2}{(a+b)^2} \\ 1 & -\frac{2}{(a+b)^2}\end{bmatrix}$ and make it small in some appropriate norm (that is to be constructed), but I have no clue how to do it. Then if we do that, an application of the mean-value theorem would give the result.

Comment: What are your attempts to solve it? This is not a problem solving community. You need to provide relevant details of your attempts towards solving the problem and any relevant context as well.

Comment: It's a question I had in mind, not an assignment. I have no clue how to do it. If you like I can add random attempts, but I'm not sure it would be more clear.

Comment: @OP. I understand it may be a genuine question and not an exercise. But it is still good practice to share your insights into answering your question.

Comment: I added what is natural (that is trying to make the derivative small), but it really is the 0th step